# Can a netlogo program take in real-time inputs from an external source?

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo seems like a fantastic way to model complex systems. However, it is used primarily as a research and education tool. As a rather fun, speculative idea, I was wondering if you could hook up a netlogo model to a sensor or some other program, and have the former take inputs from the latter in real-time, as well a provide outputs. Is this possible with netlogo at the moment?

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/netlogolab.html

Comment: In addition to the GoGo linked by Alan, NetLogo also has an [Arduino extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arduino.html) and a [vid extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/vid.html) which can take real-time camera input. If none of those are what you are looking for, as long as your sensor input can interface with Java somehow, you could write you own extension for NetLogo, too.